# MiscUtils Operator - multiply by scalar

Tags: c#, generics

I am implementing the next function:

```
private bool CheckRelativeIncrease(T pVal1, T pVal2, out T pFluctuation, int x)
```

where I compare if pVal2 has increased more than a "x%" over pVal1. I am using Generics to make the function work with int, short... I am using MiscUtils.Operator but the problem is that I can't mix known and unknown types. The following code doesn't work:

```
            bool increased = false;
   int comparer = Comparer.Default.Compare(pVal1, pVal2);
   pFluctuation = Operator<T>.Zero;
   if (comparer > 0) {
    int factor = (int)(1 + (x / 100));
    pFluctuation = Operator.Multiply(factor, pVal2);
    comparer = Comparer.Default.Compare(pVal1, pFluctuation);
    if (comparer >= 0)
     increased = true;
   }
   return increased;
```

"Operator.Multiply" gives me an error because 'factor' has not the same type as 'pVal2'.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
Silvia

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe we currently support operators on mixed types - but if you look at the code in `Operator<T>` it should be pretty easy to adapt it. Feel free to send me a patch :)

Basically you'll need an `Operator<T1, T2, TResult>` which looks like `Operator<TValue, TResult>` except it uses different types for the different inputs and outputs. You'll need to specify what the expected result type is, of course - if you're multiply `T` by `int`, would you expect the result to be `int`, `T` or something else?

If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, you may want to consider using dynamic typing instead...

Comment: Hi, thaks for the quick answer.

Comment: Thaks for the quick answer. I'll try to adapt the code, ok. In this case, the expected result would be T. Where can I download the source? I only found an old version of MiscUtils that didn't have Operator in it...

Answer (score 0):

There is also two-type multiply operation which you can use, according to [this documentation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html):

```
public static TArg1 MultiplyAlternative(TArg1 value1, TArg2 value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another function to cast one type as another type. Make a nested call to that function within your code and problem solved.